# Yii2 grid view widget sorting in desc order

Tags: yii2

i have a grid view like this

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


            'movie.movie_name',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'theatre.theatre_name',
            'screen.screen_name',
            'time.start_time',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

how can i arrange them in a descending order based on `start_date`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In search model add `sort` attribute:

```
public function search($params)
{
    ...

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['start_date' => SORT_DESC]]
    ]);
 ....
}
```